# How to make a meta box?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'd like to make a metabox with a name and a URL input on my custom post type.

I want the result to show up in my content on my post. I have a movie review site. So for example I want it to look like this:

> **Mission Impossible 5 (2012)**
>
> *Ethan Hunt is at it again, but this time it personal. The evil meta box code is stopping him from building his site!*
>
> **Youtube Link**: `youtube.com/blahblah`

Comment: there are a gazillion tutorials on this subject.  not to mention there is a working example in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Answer (score 2):

Imho, the fastest way would be by using the [Meta Box Wrapper Class](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/), which is a plugin by now. Download and activate it.

**Next in your functions.php add the following:**

```
$prefix = 'cheas_cool_metabox_';
global $meta_boxes;
$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'movie_reviews',
    'title' => 'Movie Review',
    //Change the next line if you want to display on another post type
    'pages' => array( 'post' ),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'high',

    // List of meta fields
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            // Field name - Will be used as label
            'name' => 'Movie Title',
            // Field ID, i.e. the meta key
            'id' => $prefix . 'movie_title',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Review',
            'id' => $prefix . 'movie_review',
            'type'  => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Link',
            'id' => $prefix . 'movie_link',
            'desc' => 'Youtube Link',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
    ),

);


function cheas_cool_metabox_register_meta_boxes()
{
    global $meta_boxes;

    if ( class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) )
    {
        foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box )
        {
            new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'cheas_cool_metabox_register_meta_boxes' );
```

**Now all you need to do is to call it on your post page:**

```
Movie: <?php echo rwmb_meta( 'cheas_cool_metabox_movie_title' ); ?>
Review: <?php echo rwmb_meta( 'cheas_cool_metabox_movie_review' ); ?>
Watch Trailer for <a href="<?php echo rwmb_meta( 'cheas_cool_metabox_movie_link' ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'cheas_cool_metabox_movie_title' ); ?></a>
```

This should do it for you, but check out the demo folder in the main plugin directory to see more examples of different meta box types

Comment: I used to use WP Alchemy all the time, but Rilwis' plugin/class is probably even easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to what you need to do:

1. Create the meta field (Youtube URL).
2. Output that custom meta field in your page template (probably single-movie.php).

For the first part, there is plenty of documentation available, just search 'create custom meta field/box' and follow along. Here's [an example](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/user-friendly-custom-fields-meta-boxes-wordpress) of how to do it. And for the second, you'll simply output the meta field where desired in the relevant template file.